# AngularJS ngWebscoket not send message to all user

Tags: java, angularjs, session, websocket, angularjs-scope

I am using ngWebsocket for listening user actions and update all users page according to current action not just page that who send action.

And I make a end point in java who catch all actions and send message all open sessions. but when i testing, end point find sessions and send message to all of them but message just come to person who send action.

my java code like

```
 @OnMessage
public String onMessage(Session session, String message) {    Gson gson = new Gson();
    SocketMessage sm = gson.fromJson(message, new SocketMessage().getClass());
    if (sm.getEvent().equals("teklif")) {

        Set<Session> openSessions = session.getOpenSessions();
        for (Session openSession : openSessions) {
            try {
                openSession.getBasicRemote().sendText("{\"event\":\"teklif\",\"data\":" + sm.getData() + "}");
            } catch (Exception ioe) {
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    return message;
}`
```

when i debug `Set<Session> openSessions = session.getOpenSessions();` it show me two session and send message to all remote. And I listen in my controller

```
 $rootScope.ws.$on('teklif', function (data) { console.log(data);

});
```

it is shown only person who emit the message

note : I send message like this -->`$rootScope.ws.$emit('teklif', data.content);`

How can I make this socket that all user listen all actions ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using `Session.getOpenSessions()`. The Javadoc states:

> Return a copy of the Set of all the open web socket sessions that
>   represent connections to the same endpoint to which this session
>   represents a connection. The Set includes the session this method is
>   called on. These sessions may not still be open at any point after the
>   return of this method. For example, iterating over the set at a later
>   time may yield one or more closed sessions. Developers should use
>   session.isOpen() to check.

So it does **not** give you the set of **all** client sessions connected to your endpoint.

Instead you need to keep track of all session connected to your endpoint for yourself and iterate over that set. Here is an [example](https://github.com/reta/jetty-web-sockets-jsr356/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/services/BroadcastServerEndpoint.java).

Comment: wero thanks for reply. i change the end point and i make it as example but nothing change i add all session to my set and i check that are open or not but when i try to listen in ui side socket just change action owner again.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem what is it .

```
    @OnMessage
public String onMessage(Session session, String message) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    SocketMessage sm = gson.fromJson(message, new SocketMessage().getClass());
    if (sm.getEvent().equals("teklif")) {
        //SoncketTestMessage fromJson = gson.fromJson(test.getData(), SoncketTestMessage.class);

        Set<Session> openSessions = session.getOpenSessions();
        for (Session openSession : openSessions) {
            try {
                SocketResponse rsp = new SocketResponse();
                rsp.setEvent("teklif");
                rsp.setData(gson.toJson(sm.getData()));
                //openSession.getBasicRemote().sendText("{\"event\":\"teklif\",\"data\":" + sm.getData() + "}");
                openSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(gson.toJson(rsp, SocketResponse.class));

            } catch (Exception ioe) {
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

i made a mistake at

```
openSession.getBasicRemote().sendText("{\"event\":\"teklif\",\"data\":" + sm.getData() + "}");
```

i just changed sm.getData and send right json format then it send to all user.

It send just to owner before  because of that function return message and it is at right format and only owner get the return. Now all user are getting the message.